# Unable to add header and footer for a table view controller

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, ios4

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIView *tableHeaderView;  

// accessory view for above row content. default is nil. not to be confused with section header
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIView *tableFooterView;  

// accessory view below content. default is nil. not to be confused with section footer
```

Comment: Step 2: use StackOverflow editor's formatting option for code (or just indent code with four spaces). Step 3: What's the question?

Answer (score 1):

I have added a label in footer View do inner coding according to your requirements
No need to make any global variables.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tbleView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
                UILabel *label;
            label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 30)]autorelease];
            [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
            label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
            [label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
            [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0]];
            [label setText:NSLocalizedString(@"Instructions Personal Profile",@"Instructions Personal Profile")];


        UIView *view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30)]autorelease];
          [view setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth]; 
         [view addSubview:label];
         return view;


}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
}
```

For setting the height of footer and header use:-

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
}
```